# Is there a way to bring the VS Code theme to Rider IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm using a theme called "Night owl black" in VS Code but in the Rider's marketplace there is no have that package. So is there a way to bring the VS Code theme to Rider IDE?
(I now there is night owl but it's not the same one that i use...)